# Can't Access Element Using SimpleXML PHP

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

Okay I have some problems because i cant read some part of my xml:

**file.xml**

```
<main>
 <a>
  <b>
    <c>
      ok1
    </c>
  </b>
  <b>
    <c>
      ok2
    </c>
  </b>
 </a>
</main>
```

I can open the xml file but I cant see the value of 'ok2', hope u can help me, thanks.

**file.php**

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file($filename) or die("Error: Cannot create object");
```

Im trying  this:

```
$xml->{'a'}->{'b'}[1]->{'c'} // but cant see anything
```

hope u can help, thanks

Comment: First your example xml missing an `</a>`, second try do use `xpath()` or do `print (string)$xml->a->b[1]->c; //ok2`

Comment: doenst work :S i dont know what to do

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You never close the `a` and you aren't checking for `c`.

Try:

```
$xml = new SimpleXmlElement('<main>
 <a>
  <b>
    <c>
      ok1
    </c>
  </b>
  <b>
    <c>
      ok2
    </c>
  </b>
  </a>
</main>');
echo $xml->{'a'}->{'b'}[1]->{'c'};
```

Demo: https://eval.in/638971

If you wanted it captured cleanly use `trim`.

```
echo trim($xml->{'a'}->{'b'}[1]->{'c'});
```

Comment: oh its close, i just write it bad

Comment: @Alberto Acuña Tip: without `trim()` or `(string)` you will still get an SimpleXMLElement, try it `var_export($xml->{'a'}->{'b'}[1]->{'c'});`

Comment: Can use `$xml->{'a'}->{'b'}[1]->{'c'}->__toString()` or `$xml->{'a'}->{'b'}[1]->{'c'}->asXML()` as well.

Comment: And just for the Brain: If you understand why this works too: `echo (string)$xml->{'a'}->{'b'}->{'c'};//ok1`  then you understand the tricky behaviour of SimpleXMLElements ;)